# How to read/modify/remove items/lists contained in a list in applescript

Tags: macos, csv, applescript

This question follows on from my previous question [How to transform a CSV into several lists (applescript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933145/how-to-transform-a-csv-into-several-lists-applescript#comment20962563_14933145)

I have a csv file with about 4000 lines. I import it and make each line into an item of a list, I then make each line it's own list of items.

eg: (I am using numbers but the data I have contains text as well and most of the entries are more than 1 char, some entries are also blank)

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
6,5,4,3,2,1
7,8,9,0,7,6
3,4,4,5,3,1
```

becomes

```
{"1,2,3,4,5,6","6,5,4,3,2,1","7,8,9,0,7,6","3,4,4,5,3,1"}
```

becomes

```
{{"1","2","3","4","5","6"}{"6","5","4","3","2","1"}{"7","8","9","0","7","6"}{"3","4","4","5","3","1"}}
```

now what I would like to be able to do is the following:

Delete certain items from each list, so for example I want to delete the second Item from Each list, that's "2", "5", "8" and "4"

Run calculations on certain items, so for example I want to multiply item 5 by 2

Also some of the numbers in my data have the +11 or + 17 at the end of them, I would like to know how to replace that with the matching amount of zeros, so for example if i had 5002+6 I would want to make it into 5002000000

Current code is:

```
-- Choosing your file
set csvDevices to "testfile.csv"

-- Reading file to memory
set csvDevices to read csvDevices

-- Creating Records (Single Lines)
set csvDevicesRecords to paragraphs of csvDevices

-- Remove Title Line
set csvDevicesRecords to rest of csvDevicesRecords

-- Make each line into a list
set csvDevicesValues to {}
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
repeat with i from 1 to length of csvDevicesRecords
    set end of csvDevicesValues to text items of (item i of csvDevicesRecords)
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
```

I hope the above all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not hard if you write yourself a subroutine to do the stuff for you. Here's the 3 you requested. You'll need to add other subroutines so you can do other math operations (add, subtract, and divide). Just duplicate the multiplyItemNumberByValue() subroutine and change the operator to the appropriate one and it should work with no further changes.

Good luck.

```
set listOfLists to {{"1", "2+2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}, {"6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"}, {"7", "8", "9", "0", "7", "6"}, {"3", "4", "4", "5+3", "3", "1"}}

-- before performing any other operation, expand all zeros
set listOfLists to expandZeros(listOfLists)

-- remove item 2 from every sublist
set listOfLists to removeItemNumber(listOfLists, 2)

-- multiply item 1 of every sublist by 5
set listOfLists to multiplyItemNumberByValue(listOfLists, 1, 5)




(****************** SUBROUTINES ******************)
on multiplyItemNumberByValue(listOfLists, itemNumber, theValue)
    set newList to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of listOfLists
        set thisList to item i of listOfLists
        set thisItem to item itemNumber of thisList
        set newValue to (thisItem as number) * theValue
        set item itemNumber of thisList to (newValue as text)
        set end of newList to thisList
    end repeat
    return newList
end multiplyItemNumberByValue

on removeItemNumber(listOfLists, itemNumber)
    set newList to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of listOfLists
        set thisList to item i of listOfLists
        if itemNumber is equal to 1 then
            set newSublist to items 2 thru end of thisList
        else if itemNumber is equal to (count of thisList) then
            set newSublist to items 1 thru (itemNumber - 1) of thisList
        else
            set newSublist to items 1 thru (itemNumber - 1) of thisList & items (itemNumber + 1) thru end of thisList
        end if
        set end of newList to newSublist
    end repeat
    return newList
end removeItemNumber

on expandZeros(listOfLists)
    set newList to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of listOfLists
        set thisList to item i of listOfLists
        set newSublist to {}
        repeat with j from 1 to count of thisList
            set subItem to item j of thisList
            if subItem contains "+" then
                set x to offset of "+" in subItem
                if x is equal to 0 or x is equal to 1 or x is equal to (count of subItem) then
                    set end of newSublist to subItem -- do nothing
                else
                    set a to text 1 thru (x - 1) of subItem
                    set b to text (x + 1) thru end of subItem
                    repeat (b as number) times
                        set a to a & "0"
                    end repeat
                    set end of newSublist to a
                end if
            else
                set end of newSublist to subItem -- do nothing
            end if
        end repeat
        set end of newList to newSublist
    end repeat
    return newList
end expandZeros
```

Here's the other math subroutines...

```
on divideItemNumberByValue(listOfLists, itemNumber, theValue)
    set newList to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of listOfLists
        set thisList to item i of listOfLists
        set thisItem to item itemNumber of thisList
        set newValue to (thisItem as number) / theValue
        set item itemNumber of thisList to (newValue as text)
        set end of newList to thisList
    end repeat
    return newList
end divideItemNumberByValue

on addValueToItemNumber(listOfLists, itemNumber, theValue)
    set newList to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of listOfLists
        set thisList to item i of listOfLists
        set thisItem to item itemNumber of thisList
        set newValue to (thisItem as number) + theValue
        set item itemNumber of thisList to (newValue as text)
        set end of newList to thisList
    end repeat
    return newList
end addValueToItemNumber

on subtractValueFromItemNumber(listOfLists, itemNumber, theValue)
    set newList to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of listOfLists
        set thisList to item i of listOfLists
        set thisItem to item itemNumber of thisList
        set newValue to (thisItem as number) - theValue
        set item itemNumber of thisList to (newValue as text)
        set end of newList to thisList
    end repeat
    return newList
end subtractValueFromItemNumber
```

Comment: Hello regulus6633 and thanks for the very detailed info, I have tried the 3 first subroutines, removing items works perfectly, if possible are you able to elaborate on what each part of the code does for this one as i am very interested in understanding it better.

Comment: The expand all zeros subroutine causes me one issue which is my own fault, the numbers are formated as such in my data: 4.50569E+17 with your code it keeps the . in the place it currently is but I would need to get rid of that, so the above currently becomes 4.5056900000000000000000 but I would need it to be 45056900000000000000000. Hope that makes sense

Comment: PLEASE IGNORE THE ABOVE COMMENT, I was not able to edit in time.
The expand all zeros subroutine causes me one issue which is my own fault, the numbers are formated as such in my data: 4.50569E+17 with your code it keeps the . in the place it currently is but I would need to get rid of that, so the above currently becomes 4.5056900000000000000000 but I would need it to be 450569000000000000. So instead of just replacing the +17 with 17 zeros at the end of the number, I need to multiply the number by 10 17 times. I realise I explained this wrong above so my apologies! Hope that makes sense

Comment: If you need that then look here at the "number to string" subroutine: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-02.html. That will be a good start for you, then you may need to tweak it a little to make it do exactly as you need... which will be a good learning experience for you.

Comment: Thank you very much regulus6633. I will take a look at that now. Just received Applescript 1-2-3 through the post as well so a bit of light reading ahead

Answer (score 0):

[Nigel Garvey's CSV-to-list converter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=125444#p125444) is the best I have seen.

You can call it like this:

```
    set filePath to "/Users/You/Desktop/myCsv.csv"
    set csvData to do shell script "cat " & quoted form of filePath
    set csvDevicesLists to csvToList(csvData, {trimming:true})

--> {{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}, {"6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"}, {"7", "8", "9", "0", "7", "6"}, {"3", "4", "4", "5", "3", "1"}}
```

You can pad zeros like this:

```
set xxx to {{"1", "2", "3+2", "4", "52+3", "6"}, {"6", "5", "4+5", "3", "2", "1"}}
repeat with i from 1 to count of xxx
    if (item i of xxx as text) contains "+" then
        set temp to {}
        repeat with anItem in item i of xxx
            set end of temp to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of anItem & " | sed s/+/*10^/ | bc")
        end repeat
        set item i of xxx to temp
    end if
end repeat
return xxx
```

[ASObjC Runner](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/runner_vanilla.html) provides some good tools for manipulating lists as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the only issue with the code above is that it removes any text item from the list and returns the list with only the Numbers. Also i would prefer to stick to all Apllescript while i am learning and start variations at a later stage

Comment: Are the +'s ever combined with text ? "cat23+2" or does the list look like {"23", "cat", "24+3"} ?

Answer (score -2):

It would be easier to use Ruby or Python (or almost any other language):

```
"1,2,3+11,4,5,6
6,5,4,3,2,1+17".split("\n").each { |n|
  n.gsub!(/\+(\d+)/, "0" * $1.to_i)
  c = n.split(",")
  c[4] = c[4].to_i * 5
  c.delete_at(1)
  puts c.join(",")
}
```

Comment: Hi Lauri. I would imagine that the OP would have written the script in Ruby if he or she knew it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I am trying to learn AppleScript at the moment.

Comment: -1 It is poor form to answer a question with "use another language/technology/platform etc" unless the question is specifically asking for options. That's not helpful. In many cases, Applescript is often the sole choice for certain actions. It's a pain to use but necessary so many Mac coders have to learn it. Believe me, if we had other options we would use them.